# How can I use a PQ Labs multitouch overlay with the Pi?

Tags: driver, touchscreen

I have multitouch screen overlays from PQ Labs that I would like to use with my Pi. They only have drivers for the x86 architecture.

Is there any way I can use these? If not, are there other multitouch overlays compatible with the Pi?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post some more specifics, such as the overlay manufacturer? Somebody here may have already got something similar working already, but without details...

Comment: @kolin here you go!

Answer (score 1):

If the manufacturer provides *open source* linux drivers then they could be recompiled for the pi.  There are a bunch of touchscreen drivers available for the raspbian kernel (`src/drivers/input/touchscreen`) some of which are apparently multitouch.  The list is:

```
ADS7846/TSC2046/AD7873 and AD(S)7843 based touchscreens
AD7877 based touchscreens
Analog Devices AD7879-1/AD7889-1 touchscreen interface
Atmel mXT I2C Touchscreen
BU21013 based touch panel controllers
cy8ctmg110 touchscreen
Dynapro serial touchscreen
Hampshire serial touchscreen
EETI touchscreen panel support
Fujitsu serial touchscreen
Gunze AHL-51S touchscreen
Elo serial touchscreens
Wacom W8001 penabled serial touchscreen
MAX11801 based touchscreens
MELFAS MCS-5000 touchscreen
MicroTouch serial touchscreens
iNexio serial touchscreens
ICS MicroClock MK712 touchscreen
Penmount serial touchscreen
Touchright serial touchscreen
Touchwin serial touchscreen
USB Touchscreen Driver
Sahara TouchIT-213 touchscreen
TSC-10/25/40 serial touchscreen support
TSC2005 based touchscreens
TSC2007 based touchscreens
W90P910 touchscreen driver
Sitronix ST1232 touchscreen controllers
TPS6507x based touchscreens
```

Obviously you then need userland software; **Qt** may have some support.

Answer (score 0):

Without the correct driver you get basic mouse support, but beware it becomes totally useless once you start using several fingers. It simply stops responding, so it's totally unreliable in that way.

In my experience, the drivers @goldilocks suggested will not work at all. I have tried several panels in different versions and sizes. I've exchanged emails with some chinese guys they provide as support contact.

What i've found is that there is an opensource driver, they provide it and even [annouce it on their site](http://multitouch.com/support.html). Also there is a more up to date version, but it is delivered only to confirmed customers. With few minor changes, I managed to build that one on the Pi, but unfortunatly it won't recognize the panel. I tried with several kernel versions and all i get is either unrecognizable panels or kernel panics. I have the feeling this is about some power issues or some sort of non-standard electronics or protocols. This is odd because they officially support Android.

Latest news i got from tech support (1~2 months ago) is that the new versions of the panels are standard HID and work flawlessly as a single touch mouse without any driver, just plug & play. But you have to be lucky as there are a lot of old panels on stock and you simply cannot ask to be served the recent ones. Anyway, for me, i need multitouch support, so it's not enough.

Im very interested in getting them to work, i can provide the latest opensource drivers and even remote ssh if any kernel-expert wants to dig.

Comment: Asked by [@Paul Melis](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/20535/paul-melis): Do you have the link [for the open-source driver you talked about]?

@PaulMelis sorry I rejected your edit. That is not the way SE.com works. There are comments for that ;-)

Comment: I was not able to paste the link