# Is there a big touch monitor available which works with Raspbian OS?

Tags: driver, touchscreen, monitoring

I am interested in buying a big touchscreen. I am talking about 19" - 23" . But I am not sure if Raspbian OS supports these screens out of the box or what is needed.

Did anyone already made such a setup working and can show me the steps needed?
Or does it probably work out of the box?

I googled a lot but found only small screens 3 and 7" attached. Another Blogger says that you can of course compile your own kernel having all drivers. But I would like to go for a easy way if possible.

I don't need PQ Overlay solutions, I need a screen.

Comment: Have a look here

http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/larger-touch-screen-displays

Comment: i saw it, thanks. it's not really what i searched for.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent PQLabs work as single touch (mouse). But you have to be lucky as older ones are unreliable. They are 40" and up.

See my answer here before spending any money: [How can I use a PQ Labs multitouch overlay with the Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4853/how-can-i-use-a-pq-labs-multitouch-overlay-with-the-pi/17083#17083)